# How to add grand foreignkey field to admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Maximum 250 characters')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"


class Notebook(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Maximum 250 characters')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField()



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(models.Model):
    notebook = models.ForeignKey(Notebook)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='pub_date')
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(slef):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Page, self).save(*args, **kswargs)
        self.notebook.save()
```

Now when I register `Page` model in admin.py. I get a form where I can select the `notebook` from dropdown. But `notebook` itself has a `foreignKey` of category. I have two queries now.

1. When I try to add a new page, How to get a form which has two dropdowns at the top, one for `Category` and one for `Notebook`
2. When I try to add a new `Category`, How to get a form where I can add new `Notebook` and new `Page` simultaneously?

I was able to add new `Page` from `add Category` by

```
class PageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Page
    extra = 1

class NotebookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PageInline]
```

When I tried to do the same with, `CategoryAdmin` I get an error saying `Page` has no foreignKey `Category`

Comment: Maybe try inline forms : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: As I already stated, I tried inline forms with CategoryAdmin, Please see the whole question